# How to compute this tensor product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, solution-verification, tensor-products

I need to compute this tensor product
$$ \mathbb{R}[t]_{t}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}[\frac{t^2+1}{t}]} \mathbb{R}(\frac{t^2+1}{t})=\mathbb{R}[t]_{t}\otimes_{\mathbb{R}[\frac{t^2+1}{t}]} \mathbb{R}[\frac{t^2+1}{t}]_{(0)}.$$

I know that if $\mathfrak{p}\subset A$ is a prime ideal, then for any $A$-algebra $B$ with $\phi:A\to B$ there is an isomorphism
$$B\otimes_{A}A_{\mathfrak{p}}\simeq B_{\mathfrak{p}^e}.$$
This leads me to think that the result of the tensor product I need to compute is $(\mathbb{R}[t]_{t})_{(0)}=\mathbb{R}(t)$, but I'm not convinced because I can't find an explicit isomorphism. Is this result right? Could someone help me to understand this?